# Is there a tool for viewing the content of memory addresses of my choice?

Tags: assembly, memory-address

I want to be able to type down a hex address and to see what's in this particular memory address.
How can I do this using visual studio?

Comment: @YuvalCohen: are you talking about physical addresses or process address space.

Comment: @YuvalCohen : gdb or ptrace()? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't access physical memory from a user-level program, only from the kernel.

Besides, your quest is meaningless: the kernel may assign e.g. physical page `123` to Internet explorer at one instance in time, and to Adobe Photoshop the next. So what would you gain by knowing that physical address `0x1234000` contained value `0x222` at the instant when you examined it (if you could).